# Loading of port number for Nest.js application from JSON module

Tags: node.js, typescript, configuration, nestjs

In my Nest.js based application, I'm trying to use one configuration file to define all configuration for an application.

The **configuration.json** file looks like this:

```
{
    "environment": "development",
    "backendPort": 8080,
    "appRootPath": ".",
    ...more configuration...
}
```

And in my Nest.js application's **main.ts** is:

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import configuration from "../configuration.json";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";



async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await app.listen(configuration.backendPort);
}
bootstrap();
```

I have enabled TypeScript's **resolveJsonModule** feature as mentioned in [TypeScript 2.9 Release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html) and VS code successfully recognized the import and provides IntelliSense and type checking.

But when I try to start the app via

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts
```

I get an error:

```
(node:5236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'backendPort' of undefined
    at d:\CodeDev\NestCMS\backend\src\main.ts:10:36
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (d:\CodeDev\NestCMS\backend\src\main.ts:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\CodeDev\NestCMS\backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\_bin.ts:177:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
(node:5236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Is there a way to define application port in an elegant way like I tried?**

I don't want the port number to be hard-coded in the main.ts file. I want it to be configurable by some option to allow me to deploy the same application build to different environments where the only thing differing will be the configuration.json.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes. Use this - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration part of NestJS docs to create ConfigService. You can replace dotenv with json if you want. Then:

```
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {ConfigService} from 'src/config/config.service';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

let bootstrap = async () => {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    const configService: ConfigService = app.get(ConfigService);
    await app.listen(configService.getPort);
};

bootstrap();
```

Now you can inject ConfigService in most part of your code + whle loading you can validate it using Joi. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I actually already have configuration service reading the JSON, doing validation, merging with defaults, etc. but had no idea how to access is from main.ts. This is elegant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on reading JSON in the ConfigService? This actually does not answer the question.

Answer (score 15):

Workaround in 2021:

main.ts, NestJS v8.0.4

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService: ConfigService = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
  const port = configService.get('APP_PORT');
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

Profit!

Comment: But it doesn't load JSON configuration

Answer (score 3):

Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/neconfig for elegant config NestJs app.

Just register **NeconfigModule** in your **AppModule**:

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { NeconfigModule } from 'neconfig';
import * as path from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    NeconfigModule.register({
      readers: [
        { name: 'env', file: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env') },
      ],
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then use it like that:

```js
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ConfigReader } from 'neconfig';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

(async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const config = app.get(ConfigReader);
  const port = config.getIntOrThrow('PORT');
  // const port = config.getInt('PORT', 3000);

  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have even better approach for doing that, and even simpler than this config service, so basically check my repo: https://github.com/neoteric-eu/nestjs-auth there is an example in `src/config/index.ts` how it works, package `dotenv` is quite nice, but `dotenv-safe` is far better, because if you're missing some values you won't know about that after you start a server! So basically your package.json script for development might looks like:

`"develop": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION  -r ts-node/register -r dotenv-safe/config src/index.ts"`

and then use and example of repo from above, regards!